# Как внедрить шрифт в программу?(C#, forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, шрифты

Не совсем понимаю, как внедрить шрифт из ресурсов программы. А так же как их правильно использовать. Подскажите пожалуйста свои варианты.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556147/how-do-i-embed-my-own-fonts-in-a-winforms-app

Comment: @AzizUmarov спасибо!